# Constraints not working with iAd and UIImageView

Tags: ios, ios-autolayout

I have an application which has three components: ADBannerView, Bottom view and top view. The top view and bottom view share equal heights, and the top has four image views having equal widths. I have set all the required constraints and it works as expected like this:
[image]

However, as soon as I add a fourth image, AdBannerView disappears and the height of remaining two views increases like this:

[image]

I have reviewed the constraints multiple times but I am unable to understand how adding an image makes a difference. Please help, I am stuck here. I have also shared the source code here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/o8madq1fi2qfesi/AutoLayoutIssue.zip?dl=0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add image to ImageView, then go to *Document Outline*, you will see the red error icon at the top right corner.
And if we tap it shows a lot of information about issue.
Let's use the standard instruments to fix this and click **Change Priority**. And it will works fine.
[image]